# Carga de datos de un Select y que muestre su resultado en otro select

Tags: javascript, php, html

Lo que quiero tratar de hacer es cuando haces una selección te traiga su resultado en otro select.

Ejemplo: Elegís un dato de Unidad y en Parte te traiga su resultado (como un select también ya que tiene varios datos).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Unidad y Parte son select.:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right"> Unidad: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="hidden" id="unidad_nro" value="0" />
    <input
      type="text"
      id="unidad"
      class="form-control editable"
      autocomplete="off"
      onclick="getUnidad();"
      disabled
      required
    />
    <div id="listaUnidad" style="display: none">
      <ul class="list-group" id="ulUnidad"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right"> Parte: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="hidden" id="unidad_parte_nro" value="0" />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="unipartes"
        class="form-control editable"
        autocomplete="off"
        onkeyup="getUnipartes();"
        disabled
        required
      />
      <div id="listaUnipartes" style="display: none">
        <ul class="list-group" id="ulUnipartes"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Más abajo está la function de la Unidad

```
function getUnidad() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "listaUnidad.php",
    data: {
      unidad: $("#unidad").val(),
    },
  })
    .done(function (lista) {
      var fila = "";
      $.each(lista, function (i, item) {
        fila +=
          "<li class='list-group-item' onclick='seleccionunidad(" +
          JSON.stringify(item) +
          ")'>" +
          item.unidad +
          "</li>";
      });

      $("#ulUnidad").html(fila);
      $("#listaUnidad").attr(
        "style",
        "display:block; position:absolute; z-index:3000; top: 34px;"
      );
    })
    .fail(function (a, b, c) {
      swal("ERROR", c, "error");
    });
}

function seleccionunidad(datos) {
  Object.keys(datos).forEach((key) => {
    $("#" + key).val(datos[key]);
  });
  $("#ulUnidad").html("");
  $("#listaUnidad").attr("style", "display:none;");
}
```

Aquí es donde se conecta a la base de datos de Unidad

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/terlog/clases/Conexion.php";
$objConexion = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objConexion->getConexion();
$filtro = $_POST['unidad'];

$sql = "";
$resultado = pg_query($conexion, $sql);
$datos = pg_fetch_all($resultado);
echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

Aquí está la function de Partes:

```
function getUnipartes() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "listaParte.php",
    data: {
      unipartes: $("#unipartes").val(),
    },
  })
    .done(function (lista) {
      var fila = "";
      $.each(lista, function (i, item) {
        fila +=
          "<li class='list-group-item' onclick='seleccionunipartes(" +
          JSON.stringify(item) +
          ")'>" +
          item.unipartes +
          "</li>";
      });

      $("#ulUnipartes").html(fila);
      $("#listaUnipartes").attr(
        "style",
        "display:block; position:absolute; z-index:3000; top: 34px;"
      );
    })
    .fail(function (a, b, c) {
      swal("ERROR", c, "error");
    });
}

function seleccionunipartes(datos) {
  Object.keys(datos).forEach((key) => {
    $("#" + key).val(datos[key]);
  });
  $("#ulUnipartes").html("");
  $("#listaUnipartes").attr("style", "display:none;");
}
```

Aquí conecta en la base de datos de Partes.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/terlog/clases/Conexion.php";
$objConexion = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objConexion->getConexion();
$filtro = $_POST['unipartes'];

$sql = "";
$resultado = pg_query($conexion, $sql);
$datos = pg_fetch_all($resultado);
echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

Ya he probado de varias maneras pero no consigo que los datos de un select pase a otro, les agradecería si me ayudasen.

Comment: Se conocen como [select dependientes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=select+dependientes) y hay muchas respuestas en la comunidad. Revisa si alguna de las existentes te sirve.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, gracias!